# package is installed via pip in wrong (src) directory instead of site packages

Tags: virtualenv, pip, virtualenvwrapper

I'm installing [this](https://github.com/mr-stateradio/django-exchange) package into a virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper and pip with this command:

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/mr-stateradio/django-exchange.git#egg=django_exchange-master
```

Interestingly the package is then placed into a src folder, and not into the site-packages folder which I would have expected. The package is placed into this folder:

```
<path-to-my-virtual-env>/testenv/src/django-exchange-master/exchange
```

Instead of this:

```
<path-to-my-virtual-env>/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I assume something is wrong with the pip install command I'm using or with the setup.py of the package.

Comment: LoL. Stackoverflow is really an amazing place. The details in your question help me solved the same problem that troubled me for hours.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `-e` option tells pip to install packages in “[editable](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/logic.html#editable-installs)” mode. If you remove the -e option, pip will install the package into `<venv path>/lib/Python_version/site-packages`. Don't forget to remove the packages inside `<venv path>/src`, because python looks for the packages inside `<venv path>/src` first.

pip supports installing from Git, Mercurial, Subversion and Bazaar, and detects the type of VCS using url prefixes: “git+”, “hg+”, “bzr+”, “svn+”.

e.g

```
$ pip install -e git+https://git.repo/some_pkg.git#egg=SomePackage          # from git
$ pip install -e hg+https://hg.repo/some_pkg.git#egg=SomePackage            # from mercurial
$ pip install -e svn+svn://svn.repo/some_pkg/trunk/#egg=SomePackage         # from svn
$ pip install -e git+https://git.repo/some_pkg.git@feature#egg=SomePackage  # from 'feature' branch
```

VCS projects can be installed in editable mode (using the –editable option) or not.

- For editable installs, the clone location by default is `<venv path>/src/SomeProject` in virtual environments, and `<cwd>/src/SomeProject` for global installs. The `–src` option can be used to modify this location.
- For non-editable installs, the project is built locally in a temp dir and then installed normally. `

Comment: Should be --src in pip I think?

`pip install -r ./requirements.txt --no-cache --src ~/.virtualenvs/PROJECTNAME/src`

Comment: This is right, but when installing the package from a `requirements.txt` file, if you remove the `-e` option and the URL is like `git://github.com/ORG/PACKAGE.git@TAG#egg=PACKAGE` it will fail with `ERROR: Invalid requirement` log, and prepending the `-e` argument in the requirements.txt solves the problem but with the inconvenience of having the package in the `src/` folder. Solution: instead of prefixing the URL with just `git://`, it has to be `git+git://`.